# Collection in View doesnt have the method

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have my View:

```
var TryView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function(){
    this.render();
},

render: function(){

    var test = this.collection.get(0);
    this.collection.each(function(model){
    document.write(model.id+"<br>");
    });
}
```

});

and the order to create it with some existing (working) collection.

```
var testView = new TryView({collection: test.TestCollection});
```

but i get the error:

> Object function (){ parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'get'

and the same with fetch

Comment: Where do you assign test.TestCollection? It looks like TestCollection is a function instead of a Backbone collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to call get on the 'class' `test.TestCollection`. When you do this

```
var testView = new TryView({collection: test.TestCollection});
```

you give the TestCollection 'class' (there are really no classes in js, just functions) as the `collection` -attribute to the View. You have to give an instance of TestCollection

```
var testCollection = new test.TestCollection();
var testView = new TryView({collection: testCollection});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Pass collection instance

`new TryView({collection: new test.TestCollection});`